# Django Query find most recent item in past or future

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a query working for returning the item closest to the current date and furthest from the current date. I would like to change the query to find the closest date in the future and the closest date in the past. Is there a way to limit results to only return prior or future dates?

My current query looks like this:

```
next = Product.objects.all().filter(categories__name='Subscription').filter(name__gt=date.today()).order_by("name")[0]
current = Product.objects.all().filter(categories__name='Subscription').filter(name__gt=date.today()).order_by("-name")[0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closest in the future:

```
next = Product.objects.filter(
    categories__name='Subscription'
).filter(name__gt=date.today()).order_by("name")[0]
```

Closest in the past:

```
current = Product.objects.filter(
    categories__name='Subscription'
).filter(name__lt=date.today()).order_by("-name")[0]
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups

Note that you don't need `all()` before `filter()`.